# How to change to strikethrough font styles in LyX editor through Layout file?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I've created a custom style for LyX, now I'd like to style it with a strikethrough style (in the LyX editor). Is this possible?

I'd like something like this, where the line 'Decoration    Strikethrough' is there to illustrate what I'm looking for, I don't believe either keyword exist (or at least not in that combination):

```
Style MyStrikethroughStyle
      LabelString   "My Inset"
      LatexType     Environment
      LatexName     mystyle
      Font
        Decoration  Strikethrough
        Color       Red
      EndFont
End
```

Also, would it be possible to combine a strikethrough style with something like an underline style?

Comment: Just a note that if you don't get a solution around here, feel free to join the lyx-users mailing list. There are some LyX layout experts that hang out around there. By the way (picky suggestion), it's useful if you say what does not work in what you posted above. Is it that "Decoration" tag does not actually exist or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I'll definitely post it to the mailing list if nothing shows up here. Also, you are very right to be a bit picky, I'll update the question.